# Post authentication and Get requests Restful Android

Tags: android

I have this RestFull in the URL http://api.olhovivo.sptrans.com.br/v0

```
POST /Login/Autenticar?token={token}
```

RETURN
true

```
GET /Linha/Buscar?termosBusca={termosBusca} 
RETURN
[
    {
        "CodigoLinha": 1273,
        "Circular": false,
        "Letreiro": "8000",
        "Sentido": 1,
        "Tipo": 10,
        "DenominacaoTPTS": "PCA.RAMOS DE AZEVEDO",
        "DenominacaoTSTP": "TERMINAL LAPA",
        "Informacoes": null
    },
    {
        "CodigoLinha": 34041,
        "Circular": false,
        "Letreiro": "8000",
        "Sentido": 2,
        "Tipo": 10,
        "DenominacaoTPTS": "PCA.RAMOS DE AZEVEDO",
        "DenominacaoTSTP": "TERMINAL LAPA",
        "Informacoes": null
    }
]
```

How can I authenticate and get the Json records in the GET method in android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, this.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, this.CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

// Retrieve user credentials.
SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("LOGIN", 0);
String loginNameString = settings.getString("login_name", null);
String passwordString = settings.getString("password", null);

UsernamePasswordCredentials credentials = 
         new UsernamePasswordCredentials(loginNameString, passwordString);

AuthScope authScope = new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT);
client.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(authScope,                                                                              credentials);

HttpPut put = new HttpPut(UPLOAD_URL);

try
{
    put.setEntity(new StringEntity(responseJSONArray.toString(),    
                   SERVER_PREFERRED_ENCODING));
    put.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    put.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);

    // 200 type response.
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() >= HttpStatus.SC_OK &&
    response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() < HttpStatus.SC_MULTIPLE_CHOICES)
    {
      // Handle OK response etc........
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

Comment: The Restful server need POST to authenticate 
POST /Login/Autenticar?token={token}  and GET to request a Json records like  
GET /bus/find?findthis={.......}

Comment: Your code doesnt work because I need authenticate withe Post TOKEN and use GET to request Json objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to capture the cookies from the authentication Response (as of today, the only returned cookie is `apiCredentials`), and include it into your next Requests.

(It has some timeout, so you need to refresh it by authenticating again whenever needed.)